# Angular.js redirecting from one abstract state child to another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to implement login using Angular.js with Laravel as a back end. I'm using an abstract state for handling the layout. There are 2 abstract states: 1 for public pages and 1 for admin pages. The problem is when I login, when I use `$state.go('admin.dash')` or `$window.location.href = '#/admin/dash'` it redirects me to the page but the sidebar isn't loaded. It only loads when I access the page directly or do a full page refresh on the browser.

Here's what my loginController looks like:

```
(function(){

    angular.module('starter.controllers')
    .controller('LoginController', ['$scope', 'UserService', '$state', '$window', LoginController]);
    function LoginController($scope, UserService, $state, $window){
        var me = this;

        me.loginUser = function(user){

            UserService.login(user).then(function(data){
                $window.location.href = ('#/admin/dash'); //also tried $state.go
            });

        };

    };
})();
```

And here's what the app configuration for the states look like:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    .state('home', {
      url: "/home",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/layouts/tabs.html"
    })
    .state('home.login', {
      url: '/login',
      views: {
        'home-login': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-login.html',
          controller: 'LoginController'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('admin', {
      url: "/admin",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/layouts/admin-menu.html"
    })
    .state('admin.dash', {
      url: '/dash',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/admin/dash.html'
        }
      }
    });
```

So basically I'm trying to redirect from the `home` state to the `admin` state. When I checked on chrome dev tools the HTML is actually loaded, but I don't know why the sidebar just wont show up:

[image]

Here's a screenshot when I use `$state.go` or `$window.location.href`:

[image]

And here's how it looks like when I access it directly:

[image]

Comment: You should try out $location service to change view instead of forcing window.location.href i guess. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: Did you try using `$routeProvider` from the [`ngRoute`](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) module instead?

Comment: I tried but I get the following error `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: invalid 'handler' in when()`

Comment: @Kyokasuigetsu I think that is maybe because maybe you forget to add the `'ngRoute'` tag inside your `angular.module("...", ['ngRoute']);` or maybe to add the dependency into your `bower.json` file??